# issue with ignite jars for spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, ignite, lib

I am trying to use ignite 2.4 with Spark 2.1. 
I add the path of the following libs from the binary of ignite at `spark-shell`

```
--conf spark.diver.extraClassPath=/home/sshuser/apache-ignite-fabric-2.4.0-bin/libs/*:/home/sshuser/apache-ignite-fabric-2.4.0-bin/libs/optional/*:/home/sshuser/apache-ignite-fabric-2.4.0-bin/libs/ignite-indexing/*:/home/sshuser/apache-ignite-fabric-2.4.0-bin/libs/ignite-spring/* --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=/home/sshuser/apache-ignite-fabric-2.4.0-bin/libs/*:/home/sshuser/apache-ignite-fabric-2.4.0-bin/libs/optional/*:/home/sshuser/apache-ignite-fabric-2.4.0-bin/libs/ignite-indexing/*:/home/sshuser/apache-ignite-fabric-2.4.0-bin/libs/ignite-spring/*
```

But, I cannot import any of libs such as

```
import org.apache.ignite.configuration._ 
error: object ignite is not a member of package org.apache
```

How should I resolve this?

Comment: Hi check SPARK_CLASSPATH as suggested here http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/Ignite-with-Spark-Error-td13600.html

Comment: SPARK_CLASSPATH is deprecated since spark 1.0+. Even with setting that, the problem still exist.

Comment: a combination of --driver-class-path and  --conf "spark.executor.extraClassPath" works for most imports, but adding optinal/spark-ignite/ or  optional/spark-ignite_2.10/ to support import org.apache.ignite.spark.IgniteDataFrameSettings._ leads to errors.

Answer (score 0):

1. `/home/sshuser/apache-ignite-fabric-2.4.0-bin/libs/optional/*:` - Ignite contains many subfolders in `optional`, but java doesn't include subfolders into classpath. To include spark jars you should add `/home/sshuser/apache-ignite-fabric-2.4.0-bin/libs/optional/ignite-spark/*` into classpath.
2. Please, read official documentation - https://apacheignite-fs.readme.io/v2.4/docs/installation-deployment